# How to use Paypal's exchange rates instead of webservicex?

Tags: paypal, currency

We use a variety of currencies on our store. Payments are processed only in our base currency. Unfortunately paypal uses their own rates which differ quiet a bit
from webservicex's rates.
Is there a way that our store can pull paypals rates in order to display the same price that paypal would use for their conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there seems to be no way to just get all the currency rates from paypal:
https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1976&topicID=&m=ARA

IF you find a way to get the exchange rates, you can use the module by Anna, modify it to use Paypals rates instead of the ones from the ECB:

https://github.com/LimeSoda/LimeSoda_CurrencyConverter